# Throwing GitLab Webhook error while integrating

Tags: gitlab, git-webhooks

I am getting error while adding webhook in GitLab for zohoproject.

"Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 401 {"error":{"code":6401,"message":"Unauthorized Access"}}"

I am simply adding webhook url of zoho project inside gitlab

e.g.

https://projects.zoho.com/restapi/portal/25002386/projects/545388000098456754/commits/gitlab/?authtoken=299234b2c777ee4935450b395b361d33

Answer (score 0):

[Zoho projects error codes](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/error-codes.html) are clear

> The request requires HTTP authentication.

The [GitLab Zoho integration](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/gitlab.html) has [similar error codes](https://www.zoho.com/developer/help/extensions/automation/webhooks.html)

> 401 Unauthorized - No valid Auth Token provided.

So you need to add an Auth Token, that you can [generate here](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/prerequisites/generate-auth-token.html).

Comment: is this Auth Token not a valid one "authtoken=299234b2c777ee4935450b395b361d33" embedded in link ?

Comment: @deepak If you have generated it through https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/prerequisites/generate-auth-token.html, it should be a valid one.

Comment: @deepak But double-check the URL: https://www.zoho.com/developer/help/extensions/automation/webhooks.html#Configure_webhook. I see "URL to Notify:
 `https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/write`"